# Parametrization of cirular segment

Tags: calculus

I have the following set
$$
M:=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} | x^2+y^2 \leq 4 , x \geq1 \}
$$
Eventually I intend to integrate over M, so I would like to parametrize it.

What is the best approach?

Comment: Your are completely right. I just edited it. The radius of the circle is supposed to be 4.

Answer (score 0):

You are given the disk of radius 2, with the center in the origin $O(0,0)$, so here are some starting points:

$$
x = r \cos{\theta} \\
y = r \sin{\theta} \\
r \in [0,2] \\
x \geq 1 \rightarrow r\cos{\theta} \geq 1
$$

Comment: M is clearly a 2-dimensional surface, so I need a parametrization in two variables, hence the radius can´t be constant. Shouldn´t the angle depend on the radius? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Look for my updated answer.